# AbortedError: Session 902faae618c6a822 is not found

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tpu

this is my code , it donest work with tpu,but it works in cpu/gpu mode in google colab, i dont know why, anyone know the reason?

my tensorflow version is 1.15.0
the x_train.shape is (13887, 3000),the y_train.shape is (13887,8)
and the 
num_features = 301+1
sequence_length = 3000
embedding_dimension = 1000
thx very much!

```
filter_sizes=[2,2,3,4]
def convolution():
    inn = layers.Input(shape=(sequence_length, embedding_dimension, 1))
    cnns = []
    for size in filter_sizes:
        conv = layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(size, embedding_dimension),
                            strides=1, padding='valid', activation='elu')(inn)
        pool = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(sequence_length-size+1, 1), padding='valid')(conv)
        cnns.append(pool)
    outt = layers.concatenate(cnns)

    model = keras.Model(inputs=inn, outputs=outt)
    return model
```

```
def cnn_mulfilter():
    model = keras.Sequential([
        layers.Embedding(input_dim=num_features, output_dim=embedding_dimension,
                        input_length=sequence_length),
        layers.Reshape((sequence_length, embedding_dimension, 1)),
        convolution(),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(20, activation='elu'),
        layers.Dropout(0.2),
        layers.Dense(8, activation='softmax')

    ])
    return model
```

```
import os

resolver = tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver('grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])
tf.contrib.distribute.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
strategy = tf.contrib.distribute.TPUStrategy(resolver)

with strategy.scope():
  model = cnn_mulfilter()
  model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4),
                 loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
                 metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train.astype(np.float32), y_train.astype(np.float32),
            steps_per_epoch=batch_size,
            epochs=30,
            validation_data=(x_test.astype(np.float32), y_test.astype(np.float32)),
            validation_freq=30)
```

the error is as below

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1364     try:
-> 1365       return fn(*args)
   1366     except errors.OpError as e:

10 frames
AbortedError: Session e6d3a6fe721e9009 is not found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AbortedError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1382                     '\nsession_config.graph_options.rewrite_options.'
   1383                     'disable_meta_optimizer = True')
-> 1384       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1385 
   1386   def _extend_graph(self):

AbortedError: Session e6d3a6fe721e9009 is not found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the file is in the local filesystem which is not supported by TPU, the error message is very strange though.

Moving to TFRecords instead solved the problem.